# How do I prevent being kicked back to the login screen every time?

Tags: 13.04, login-screen, macbook, 13.10

Just finished upgrading from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. Everything works fine. After the installations, I restart to finish the installations. In the log in screen, I put my password and then it goes back to the log in screen. I've tried so many times, still the same.

Note: Using Unity, running 13.04 before using MacBook Air with single OS.

Comment: Same here. Please help.

Comment: I saw a quick-flash message: "Could not acquire name on session bus" after entering the password and hitting <enter>.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10.
None of the solutions here worked for me, so I found [this bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1188947). I removed Cinnamon/Nemo with `sudo apt-get remove --purge cinnamon*` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Tried cinnamon didn't work. Read about the permission issue on the .Xauthority file. Sorry, I lost the link to that answer

1. Logged in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as the user
2. and removed the .Xauthority file
3. went back to GUI session by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Worked like a charm!!

Comment: It would be nice if you could look up where the file is located and [edit] the post to add it in.

Comment: @JulianStirling it's in your home folder (~)

Answer (score 0):

At the login screen press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login as normal user, then execute:`sudo su`
**No errors should happen** (if errors happens write them here!) and your prompt will be with an "#" character at the end, you are root now: don't do stupid things and run `exit` to return a normal user.
After this check let's reconfigure your login manager, execute: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and, eventually, select gdm as your default login manager.
Execute `sudo killall Xorg`; after that you will be asked to login (if don't press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) without any error: try to login.
If it still don't work, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, run `passwd` and change the password; execute `sudo killall Xorg` and try to login with the new password.
If it still doesn't work (damn! :-) ) return to the virtual terminal and execute `rm ~/.Xauthority`, then `sudo killall Xorg` and try to login.
*The password asked with "sudo" is your user password*, never forget your password.
If the login still doesn't work, it's a more complicate case, report here any error.

Comment: When I type CTRL+ALT+F1, Login as normal user and type sudo su and dpkg-reconfigure gdm and it tells me that gdm is not install. by the way, Ubuntu 13.10 comes with 3.11 Kernel right? why am i list as 3.9?

Comment: Well, no luck. Root check was OK. But I was not able to make any selection during reconfiguring gdm. The system just showed "/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: gdm ..." and then returned to the prompt. Also, nothing happened when pressing CTRL+ALT+F7; is "F7" correct?

Comment: Follow all the solutions you provide, none of them works.

Comment: **user203648: run `uname -a` to know what kernel you're using. Run on a terminal `sudo apt-get install gdm` and reboot.
**Tang: yes, dpkg-reconfigure MAY offer you a choice if more than one compatible login manager is installed; CTRL+ALT+F7 is correct (Xorg goes on tty7 by default; more instances WILL go to tty8,9 ecc.), maybe you didn't start Xorg. Follow the procedure another time, if doesn't work (try others CTRL+ALT+Fn) execute `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log|grep WW` and `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log|grep EE`, the post here the errors.
It's an interesting problem.

Comment: *On behalf of user [hewhocutsdown](http://askubuntu.com/users/5223/hewhocutsdown):* I tried everything you said, to no avail.

Comment: *There is no universal solution*. Try the Ramon Egger's response. I **suggest**: try to remove your login manager from a virtual terminal, you should be able to open a session directly; pay attention, because it will expose your system to undesired access from local users. If you still can't open a session you have a trouble with the GUI enviroment and not with the login manager (the object of our problem-solving session); you can change it with an alternative. It can be a time-consuming task to check for a great amount of problems, you can still downgrade and enable security updates.

Answer (score 0):

I could temporary get past this problem by changing from Ubuntu Default to Cinnamon, at least it lets me access the files. Really wondering why is it Unity's broken...

Comment: This is not really answering the question for the OP unless he also has cinnamon installed as well. Perhaps you can rewrite the post to have it answer the question better?

Answer (score 0):

I had that same issue, i was not having cinnamon installed. Just the default Ubuntu desktop environment. After looking for alternatives without success, i did the following that fix my problem.

1. Since it is impossible to login back with Unity, i took the decision to install cinnamon on it (which will break Unity)
2. At the login screen press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login as normal user.
3. Type in the following commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install cinnamon
   ```
4. After installing all the necessary packages, just log out and change the log-in option to Cinnamon.
5. You should be able to log into your system now with Cinnamon.

I believe the problem is with Unity, can't find out how or why but a great fix to that issue will be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem this morning just after running some regular updates - I tried all sorts of things like deleting .Xauthority etc but in the end I tried reinstalling my nvidia driver which seemed to fix the login screen problem.

http://www.boliston.com/2014/01/11/ubuntu-13-10-login-screen-problem/