# Login loop after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, login, 13.10

Ubuntu has upgraded to 13.10, but when I reboot I can't login, even when I try with the guest session.  I am brought back to the login screen.

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login. Then I remove the file `~/.Xautohrity` and reboot. After that it can login from LightDM but a new error appears:

```
Could not acquire name on session bus
```

and when I reboot it can't login again.

How can I fix this? Note that I have another Desktop environment installed alongside Unity.

Comment: What do you mean "can't login"? Is your password rejected? Do you see an error message? Or are you brought back to the login screen right after? In the latter case: I've seen at least five questions about that today so please use the search for that. Please **edit** your question to include those details.

Comment: I'm being brought back to the login screen right after. I will look up for similar posts.

Comment: Again: please **edit** your question to include that - it's how this site works; it's not a discussion forum, you see?

Comment: Relevant (or even duplicate, but not able to mark as such - no upvoted answers). [How do I prevent being kicked back to the login screen every time?](http://askubuntu.com/q/360336/88802)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem but fixed it by removing Cinnamon. If this is also the case for you, try the following: `sudo apt-get remove --purge cinnamon*` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove`

If you don't have cinnamon installed but any other desktop environment alongside Unity, try to uninstall those. (Gnome fallback should be fine though)

Comment: Ok, that helps me :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved by opening the terminal (Alt+Ctrl+T) and enter:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --show-manual-login true
```

Restart the computer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wasn't able to login to my user account then I logged in as guest and in terminal switched to my user account as I didn't know what is the password for guest account then typed this command and restart:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --show-manual-login true
```

It will give you three options when you want to login again after a restart:

1. Your user account
2. Manual login by typing the user name and password
3. Guest

The 'manual login' option worked for me.