# Can't login after installing libimobiledevice

Tags: login

I am using ubuntu 13.10 and just installed libimobiledevice from Software Centre. I rebooted after the install and now I am unable to log in. I get to the login in screen, enter my password for my user name and get stuck at that point. It will not go any further.

My problem seems very similar to this thread as they also installed libimobiledevice.

[unable to type in password at login screen after restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437850/unable-to-type-in-password-at-login-screen-after-restart?newreg=9c08fe56f539498ca85d6ff52a2d3805)

I would have chimed in on that post but I am new user and not allowed to comment.

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean "It will go no further"? What happens when you input your password and press <enter>? Can you get to a tty?

Comment: after typing in the password the username box turns a darker shade of grey, and nothing happens. I can get to a tty and I can also click the mouse in the top right corner to restart or shutdown

Comment: Login to the tty and try purging libmobiledevice. Why'd you install it anyway?

Comment: ok i just ran apt-get purge libimobiledevice4. The command worked and removed it but i am still having the same issue after rebooting. I installed it so I could access my iphone

Comment: It probably wasn't the library, but it's always best to backtrack as much as possible. Were any updates installed recently? Have you check this question out? http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Comment: I believe I did run software updater this morning and it updated the ubuntu base from memory. I have tried the suggestions on the page you provided but to no avail. Also my situation is different as it is not a login loop but rather just seems to get stuck after entering the password

Comment: Can you get some of the logs files from the tty then? Paste them to paste.ubuntu.com and link them here. Thanks

Comment: not really sure how I would do that from that computer? i am using a different one to talk to you now

Comment: ok so after looking at this page http://askubuntu.com/questions/360336/how-do-i-prevent-being-kicked-back-to-the-login-screen-every-time I installed gdm and can now log into what looks like unity but has no sidebar, or top panel, only what I think is cairo dock down the bottom.

Comment: I created a Q/A [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/440087/how-do-i-get-information-from-the-logs-on-my-computer-when-i-only-have-access-to/440088#440088) for information on getting the log files out of a tty. We want to look at `Xorg.0.log` and `xsession-errors` first I'd say.