# Ubuntu logs out immediately after logs in

Tags: login

Today when i try to login to my ubuntu main user(not guest),Emad Helmi,after i typed my password it logged in and immediately logged out back to the login page, i try several times,but the same result,finally i hit `ctrl` + `alt` + `F6` and then typed `emadhelmi` and the my password after that i run this code, without and chaging directory:

```
sudo rm -v .Xauthority
```

and after that:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

i tried again to logging in to my account but the same problem.How can i fixed it?

Comment: Do you have another account? Does it respond the same way? If not make one and tell us what happens.

Comment: @JaredRosenberg : no, in the login start page of ubuntu it has 2option guest and Emad Helmi, the guest is correct and works fine(now, i am typing there-from the guest user)but Emad Helmi immediately after logging in, logging out!

Comment: Look inside `~/.xsession-errors`. Please upload the output to paste.ubuntu.com. (see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/440088/44179) Q/A if you're not sure how to do that from the command-line). Please also [edit] your question with the output of `ls -ld /tmp`. Take a look through: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop, it offers most of this advice.